# Extract texts from xps document to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, xps, xpsdocument

I keep running in to this code when researching, however copying this to my form gives me an error in the `documentViewerElement` part saying `The name 'documentViewerElement' does not exist in the current context`

```
XpsDocument _xpsDocument=new XpsDocument("/path",System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
IXpsFixedDocumentSequenceReader fixedDocSeqReader 
    =_xpsDocument.FixedDocumentSequenceReader;
IXpsFixedDocumentReader _document = fixedDocSeqReader.FixedDocuments[0];
IXpsFixedPageReader _page 
    = _document.FixedPages[documentViewerElement.MasterPageNumber];
StringBuilder _currentText = new StringBuilder();
System.Xml.XmlReader _pageContentReader = _page.XmlReader;
if (_pageContentReader != null)
{
  while (_pageContentReader.Read())
  {
    if (_pageContentReader.Name == "Glyphs")
    {
      if (_pageContentReader.HasAttributes)
      {
        if (_pageContentReader.GetAttribute("UnicodeString") != null )
        {                                   
          _currentText.
            Append(_pageContentReader.
            GetAttribute("UnicodeString"));                              
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
string _fullPageText = _currentText.ToString();
```

I'm hoping to get all the texts from an xps document and put it on a rich text box.

Comment: Without stating the obvious... You have not assigned the variable documentViewerElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

documentViewerElement is not defined hence your error.

In the following line:

```
IXpsFixedPageReader _page 
= _document.FixedPages[documentViewerElement.MasterPageNumber];
```

documentViewerElement.MasterPageNumber is just the page number, so change it to the xps page you want to read, e.g.

```
IXpsFixedPageReader _page 
= _document.FixedPages[0];
```

To read the text from the entire xps file you could try the following (it's pretty much the same as your code it's just looping (Taken from [here](http://itquestionz.com/questions/2047403/extract-text-from-a-xps-document)).

```
private string ReadXpsFile(string fileName)
{
    XpsDocument _xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(fileName, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
    IXpsFixedDocumentSequenceReader fixedDocSeqReader = _xpsDocument.FixedDocumentSequenceReader;
    IXpsFixedDocumentReader _document = fixedDocSeqReader.FixedDocuments[0];
    FixedDocumentSequence sequence = _xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
    string _fullPageText="";

    for (int pageCount = 0; pageCount < sequence.DocumentPaginator.PageCount; ++pageCount)
    {
        IXpsFixedPageReader _page = _document.FixedPages[pageCount];
        StringBuilder _currentText = new StringBuilder();
        System.Xml.XmlReader _pageContentReader = _page.XmlReader;

        if (_pageContentReader != null)
        {
            while (_pageContentReader.Read())
            {
                if (_pageContentReader.Name == "Glyphs")
                {
                    if (_pageContentReader.HasAttributes)
                    {
                        if (_pageContentReader.GetAttribute("UnicodeString") != null)
                        {
                            _currentText.
                              Append(_pageContentReader.
                              GetAttribute("UnicodeString"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        _fullPageText += _currentText.ToString();
    }

    return _fullPageText;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error `FixedDocumentSequence sequence` saying the namespace could not be found. I added the references to `PresentationCore` and `PresentationFramework` but still can't figure out what I need to do to fix it. Could you help?

Comment: The class FixedDocumentSequence is within the namespace System.Windows.Documents .. add a reference to that.