# C# Extract Text from .XPS Document

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have been using [Another StackOverflow answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962073/extract-texts-from-xps-document-to-textbox) as a reference to solving this problem, however I have run into a problem. I am getting an error at `FixedDocumentSequence` saying that it could not be found. I have added references to `PresentationCore`, `PresentationFramework`, `WindowsBase` and `ReachFramework` already, and I'm not quite sure if I need to add another reference for the `FixedDocumentSequence`.

Here is my code:

```
public string convertXPS(string fileName)
    {

        XpsDocument _xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(fileName, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
        IXpsFixedDocumentSequenceReader fixedDocSeqReader = _xpsDocument.FixedDocumentSequenceReader;
        IXpsFixedDocumentReader _document = fixedDocSeqReader.FixedDocuments[0];
        FixedDocumentSequence sequence = _xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
        string _fullPageText = "";

        for (int pageCount = 0; pageCount < sequence.DocumentPaginator.PageCount; ++pageCount)
        {
            IXpsFixedPageReader _page = _document.FixedPages[pageCount];
            StringBuilder _currentText = new StringBuilder();
            System.Xml.XmlReader _pageContentReader = _page.XmlReader;

            if (_pageContentReader != null)
            {
                while (_pageContentReader.Read())
                {
                    if (_pageContentReader.Name == "Glyphs")
                    {
                        if (_pageContentReader.HasAttributes)
                        {
                            if (_pageContentReader.GetAttribute("UnicodeString") != null)
                            {
                                _currentText.
                                  Append(_pageContentReader.
                                  GetAttribute("UnicodeString"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            _fullPageText += _currentText.ToString();
        }

        return _fullPageText;




    }
```

Comment: I'm doing the same thing using the same reference code, i don't remember what i did to make the error go away because i tried many things, but check this out add [STAThread] above the main program and try, also if that works and your xps documented is read, give a heads up, i'm stuck with this

Comment: Hey buddy, i was just successful in reading text from a XPS, finally i am happy that i did it, so you can use that to read the text, but for me unfortunately my xps consists of images rather than text, so i need to read the text from the image

Answer (score 0):

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    try
    {
        XpsDocument _xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(@"C:\Users\admin-\Desktop\testing.xps", System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
        IXpsFixedDocumentSequenceReader fixedDocSeqReader = _xpsDocument.FixedDocumentSequenceReader;
        IXpsFixedDocumentReader _document = fixedDocSeqReader.FixedDocuments[0];
        FixedDocumentSequence sequence = _xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
        string _fullPageText = "";

        for (int pageCount = 0; pageCount < sequence.DocumentPaginator.PageCount; ++pageCount)
        {
            IXpsFixedPageReader _page = _document.FixedPages[pageCount];
            StringBuilder _currentText = new StringBuilder();
            System.Xml.XmlReader _pageContentReader = _page.XmlReader;

            if (_pageContentReader != null)
            {
                while (_pageContentReader.Read())
                {
                    if (_pageContentReader.Name == "Glyphs")
                    {
                        if (_pageContentReader.HasAttributes)
                        {
                            if (_pageContentReader.GetAttribute("UnicodeString") != null)
                            {
                                _currentText.
                                  Append(_pageContentReader.
                                  GetAttribute("UnicodeString"));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            _fullPageText += _currentText.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

I don't think there is much change in the code, try to add the [STAThread] which helped me to read the xps, also i only used the above mentioned references to read the file,also i got the same error that you got, but somehow solved it, you are 90% closer to get the result
Also see which reference is needed to add `System.Windows.Documents;`